# Selecting newly generated shapes by `Offset` function in Visio VBA

Tags: vba, visio

I am an absolute novice in VBA. I want to select newly generated shapes by `Offset` function in Visio VBA.

```
Sub Offset_Example()
 Dim sel As Visio.Selection
Set sel = ActiveWindow.Selection
 sel.Offset 0.06
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long try and error, I counted shapes on the page before and after Offset function then selected last added shape indices

```
Public Sub makeborder()

Dim intCounter As Integer
Dim intShapeCount As Integer
Dim intShapeCount2 As Integer
Dim vsoShapes As Visio.Shapes
Dim vsoShapes2 As Visio.Shapes
Dim vsoSelection As Visio.Selection

Set vsoShapes = ActivePage.Shapes

intShapeCount = vsoShapes.Count

Application.ActiveWindow.Selection.Offset 0.045
Set vsoShapes2 = ActivePage.Shapes
intShapeCount2 = vsoShapes2.Count
ActiveWindow.DeselectAll
Set vsoSelection = ActiveWindow.Selection
For intCounter = intShapeCount + 1 To intShapeCount2
vsoSelection.Select vsoShapes(intCounter), visSelect
Next intCounter

vsoSelection.Union

End Sub
```